# Serializing BigDecimal value using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, bigdecimal

here is my code:

```
System.out.println(GSON.toJson(new BigDecimal(10.12)));
```

and the output is:

```
10.1199999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
```

Is it possible to limit the precision of BigDecimal value that GSON serialize? i.e. my expected output of serialized value is:

```
10.11
```

Comment: `System.out.println(GSON.toJson(new BigDecimal("10.12")));`

Comment: The issue is not with json serialization, but your use of big decimals. Use the string constructor, not the double. A double can almost never be accurately represented in memory. You write 10.12, but the machine understand 10.1199999...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `GSON` issue. `new BigDecimal()` try to represent double accurately and ends up taking lot more digits.

You can use `BigDecimal.valueOf(10.12)` or `new BigDecimal("10.12")` instead of `new BigDecimal()`.

```
System.out.println(GSON.toJson(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.12)));
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem here isn't with **GSON** but with your `BigDecimal` value instead.

If you use the `new BigDecimal(double value)` constructor you can have unpredictable results.

If you take a look at [**BigDecima(double value)** constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) it clearly says :

> **Notes:**
>
> - The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>     might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>     BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>     a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>     0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>     matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>     that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>     0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> - The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:
>     writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which is exactly
>     equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally
>     recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this
>     one.

So it's better to use the **[BigDecimal `String` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String))** here:

```
new BigDecimal("10.12")
```

Comment: I don't think "unpredictable" is the right term. I would perhaps say "unexpected", but one can very well predict the result.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes indeed you are right about it, but I just used the term in the documentation. :)