# API/REST request. Limit a number to two fractional digits. Strings are not supported

Tags: rest

I am trying to make an RESTful request to an api. The endpoint needs a number (actually money value), which cannot exceed the normal fractional digits for that currency.

I cannot use a String -> 500 - Bad request
If I use a double I get an error for doubles that have rounding errors (and thus to many digits).

So in the end if I have a value like "23.42", I need to pass this to my json as 23.42 without quaotation marks.

I am using java and the original value is stored as a BigDecimal.

I am using GSON if this is important

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serializing BigDecimal value using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076637/serializing-bigdecimal-value-using-gson)

Comment: Actually it does..Wow. I actually used toPlainString(), as I did not think about the most obvious case of letting GSON handle it ... feeling stupid. Thanks a lot